# Stringr str_replace_all misses repeated terms

Tags: r, regex, str-replace, stringr

I'm having an issue with the *stringr::str_replace_all* function.  I'm trying to replace all instances of *iv* with *insuredvehicle*, but the function only seems to catch the first term.

```
temp_data <- data.table(text = 'the driver of the 1st vehicle hit the iv iv at a stop')
temp_data[, new_text := stringr::str_replace_all(pattern = ' iv ', replacement = ' insuredvehicle ', string = text)]
```

The outcome looks like the following, which missed the 2nd *iv* term:

> 1: the driver of the 1st vehicle hit the insuredvehicle iv at a stop

I believe the issue is that the 2 instances share a space, which is part of the search pattern.  I did that because I want to replace the *iv* term, and not *iv* within *driver*.

I DON'T want to simply consolidate the repeated terms to 1.  I'd like the result to look like:

> 1: the driver of the 1st vehicle hit the insuredvehicle insuredvehicle  at a stop

I'd appreciate any help getting this to work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe if you include a word boundary in your regex, than remove the white spaces from the replacement? It is ideal when you want just a full word matching the pattern, but not parts of words, while staying away from these blank space issues.
`\\b`seems to do the trick

```
temp_data[, new_text := stringr::str_replace_all(pattern = '\\biv\\b', replacement = 'insuredvehicle', string = text)]

new_text

1: the driver of the 1st vehicle hit the insuredvehicle insuredvehicle at a stop
```

Comment: This was really simple and worked seamlessly with the other code I was running.  Seems like a better solution than having spaces around the pattern.  Makes it a little harder to read but gets the job done!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use lookarounds:

```r
temp_data[, new_text := stringr::str_replace_all(pattern = '(?<= )iv(?= )', replacement = 'insuredvehicle', string = text)]
```

Output:

```r
"the driver of the 1st vehicle hit the insuredvehicle insuredvehicle at a stop"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `gsub`:

```
gsub("\\biv\\b", "insuredvehicle", temp_data$text)
[1] "the driver of the 1st vehicle hit the uninsuredvehicle uninsuredvehicle at a stop"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use space boundaries:

```r
temp_data <- data.table(text = 'the driver of the 1st vehicle hit the iv iv at a stop')
temp_data[, new_text := stringr::str_replace_all(pattern = '(?<!\\S)iv(?!\\S)', replacement = 'insuredvehicle', string = text)]
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/0thjcJ/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```r
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \S                       non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                             and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  iv                       'iv'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \S                       non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                             and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: I really appreciate the explanation!  This is really helpful in knowing what's happening with the regex.  I like this solution because it makes the search pattern fairly easy to see.